# iOS 10 Launch Screen Bug

Tags: storyboard, xib, ios10, xcode8, launch-screen

My Device and Simulator seem to be caching the launch screen for my app!

I have deleted the original Launch Screen.storyboard and created my own XIB and swift files called "StartingPointView.xib" and "StartingPointView.Swift". The XIB file contains a view with Blue background color. It is also linked in the Xcode project settings under app icon and launch images.

So far everything seems fine, but when I change the color of the StartingPointView's view to say Yellow, the app continues to launch with a Blue screen and then flash a yellow screen.

Where is the blue coming from? (Note: I have no other blue screens in any of my UI and I tried running clean and clean build folder)

Comment: Now I'm noticing that this behavior exists even if you use the default launch screen story board file... Setting an image on it once, will cause it to be "cached" even when the image is modified. Anyone else experience this?

Comment: I ran into this issue back in January (on older versions of iOS obviously), and back then power-cycling the device would fix it. My testers are reporting similar problems to yours now, but on iOS10 a power-cycle doesn't seem to clear the cache.

Comment: Yes, power cycling didn't do it for me... buying an iPhone 7 to replace my 6 didn't help either :)

Comment: Got the same problem. I have even renamed the storyboard file and reuse the launch image, it still loaded the old storyboard file. So stupid!

Comment: Is this problem remains after installing new app version from App Store?

Answer (score 10):

This issue is directly related to [rdar://24618582](http://openradar.appspot.com/24618582) "Xcode 7.2.1: Cached Launch Screen Does Not Update" which has existed since iOS 9.

The only workaround that I've found is to completely remove and re-install your application.  I know this isn't really viable solution, but is the best that I can provide (besides restarting the device) until Apple fixes this runtime issue.